# Localized resource file created with T4 not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, t4

In my (Web) project I've created 2 regular resource files:

**strings.resx** with some string values (this file also has a strings.designer.cs)

**strings.en-US.resx** with some translated string values (set to no code generation)

When I change the culture during the request to en-US, the localized resource file is used and all strings are displayed in English (when available).

I now added 2 T4 templates files to auto generate the resource file (now, when testing, some hardcoded values, values will be loaded from DB later on):

**strings2.tt** which will create a strings2.resx file while VS automaticly creates a strings2.designer.cs file.

**strings2.en-US.tt** which will create the strings2.en-US.resx file (also no code generation).

All output files are looking equal, all files are successfully build and the T4 files are transformed without any problems. However when I try to retreive a localized string from the T4 generated resource file after I changed the culture, it won't return the English variant.

I can't see any cause for this problem, moving all resource files to a separate project doesn't solve it.

Do I miss something or is this just because the files are autogenerated?

Comment: I reproduced the issue, it is weird. If you open the csproj file in the text editor and delete the line `<DependentUpon>strings2.en-US.resx</DependentUpon>` then it should start working, but this line is always re-created when .tt is saved or the custom tool is run...

Comment: Unfortunately this line does't even exists in my projectfile.